# Firing GTM event and simultaneously updating history API with replaceState

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, html5-history, google-datalayer

When firing a GTM tag like this:

```
dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'gtm.trackEvent',
        'eventCategory': 'Offices',
        'eventAction': 'Search',
        'eventLabel': '1234AB',
        'eventNonInteraction': 1
});
```

while also updating the URL bar with the history API like so:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', '/offices?office=1234AB');
```

the URL bar behaves unexpectedly. What happens is this:

1. The URL bar starts from the current state (e.g. /path?office=current-param
2. The URL bar gets replaced by the History API (e.g. /path?office=1234AB)
3. The URL bar gets replaced by the very first state of the page view (e.g. /path?param=first-state

The only way when the third part doesn't occur, is when I disable/comment the GTM tag. Therefore I'm assuming GTM doesn't handle states with the History API well.

I was wondering if there was a possibility to disable whatever happens with the History API inside GTM.

**UPDATE**
With the `eventCallback` property, I can ensure that whenever the event has been fired, the history replaceState always gets called afterwards, which results in a correct end state (/path?office=1234AB). The code that I have now is:

```
dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'gtm.trackEvent',
        'eventCategory': 'Offices',
        'eventAction': 'Search',
        'eventLabel': '1234AB',
        'eventNonInteraction': 1,
        'eventCallback': function() {
            window.history.replaceState({}, '', '/offices?office=1234AB');
        }
});
```

Still I see the jump from the original state the new state: (point 2 and 3 switched)

1. The URL bar starts from the current state (e.g. /path?office=current-param
2. The URL bar gets replaced by the very first state of the page view (e.g. /path?param=first-state
3. The URL bar gets replaced by the History API (e.g. /path?office=1234AB)

Comment: Are you sure that there is no tags that utilize history API in GTM so you get this behavior?

Comment: Looking at the dataLayer, the only thing that happens apart from this trackEvent is the default gtm.click on a form submit.

Comment: And what about tags? Maybe some custom HTML